# jQuery append text to multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append the same text from a input field to other multiple fields when a button is clicked.

Here is the form :

```
<div class="affiliate-id-form">
    <input type="text" name="affiliateID" id="affiliateID" placeholder="Enter your affiliate ID  eg. 124531" />
    <input type="button" name="generate-links" id="btnGenerateLinks" value="Generate Links">
</div>
```

And here is the code of the input fields where I want the text to be appended.

```
<div class="affiliate-links">
    <table class="affiliateLinksTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://firstproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> Second Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://secondproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://thirdproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://fourthproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://fifthproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://sixthproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://seventhproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div >
```

Comment: `id` of element in `document` should be unique. Substitute `class="affiliateLinkGenerated"` for `id="affiliateLinkGenerated"` at `<input>` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to not just append but also each time replace the `"A="` so with this assumption i  have added a `data attribute` in your html for each input `data-link="http://firstproduct.html?A="`. This way you can do very easy.

```js
$('#btnGenerateLinks').on('click', function() {
  var valNeed = $('#affiliateID').val();

  // if (valNeed.trim().length) { // In case you want filter blank string
    $('input[name="affiliate-link"]').each(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).data('link') + valNeed);
    })
 // }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="affiliate-id-form">
  <input type="text" name="affiliateID" id="affiliateID" placeholder="Enter your affiliate ID  eg. 124531" />
  <input type="button" name="generate-links" id="btnGenerateLinks" value="Generate Links">
</div>


<div class="affiliate-links">
  <table class="affiliateLinksTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" data-link="http://firstproduct.html?A=" name="affiliate-link" value="http://firstproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">Second Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" data-link="http://secondproduct.html?A=" name="affiliate-link" value="http://secondproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" data-link="http://thirdproduct.html?A=" name="affiliate-link" value="http://thirdproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" data-link="http://fourthproduct.html?A=" name="affiliate-link" value="http://fourthproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" data-link="http://fifthproduct.html?A=" name="affiliate-link" value="http://fifthproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" data-link="http://sixthproduct.html?A=" name="affiliate-link" value="http://sixthproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" data-link="http://seventhproduct.html?A=" name="affiliate-link" value="http://seventhproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btnGenerateLinks").on("click", function() {
  $(".myClass").each(function() {
     $(this).val($(this).val() + $("#affiliateID").val()); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="affiliate-links">
    <table class="affiliateLinksTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input class="myClass" id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://firstproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> Second Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input class="myClass" id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://secondproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input class="myClass" id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://thirdproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input class="myClass" id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://fourthproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input class="myClass" id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://fifthproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input class="myClass" id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://sixthproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for=""> FIrst Product Name</label></td>
                <td><input class="myClass" id="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://seventhproduct.html?A="></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div >
  
  <div class="affiliate-id-form">
    <input type="text" name="affiliateID" id="affiliateID" placeholder="Enter your affiliate ID  eg. 124531" />
    <input type="button" name="generate-links" id="btnGenerateLinks" value="Generate Links">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` of element in `document` should be unique. Substitute `class="affiliateLinkGenerated"` for `id="affiliateLinkGenerated"` at `<input>` elements.

Attach `click` event to `"btnGenerateLinks"` element, use `.querySelectorAll()` to select `".affiliateLinkGenerated"` `input` elements, iterate elements at `for` loop, set `.value` of each element to `.previousElementSibling` of clicked `<input type="button">` element.

```js
document.getElementById("btnGenerateLinks")
.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var prev = this.previousElementSibling;
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".affiliateLinkGenerated");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = prev.value;
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="affiliate-id-form">
    <input type="text" name="affiliateID" id="affiliateID" placeholder="Enter your affiliate ID  eg. 124531" />
    <input type="button" name="generate-links" id="btnGenerateLinks" value="Generate Links">
</div>

<div class="affiliate-links">
  <table class="affiliateLinksTable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://firstproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">Second Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://secondproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://thirdproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://fourthproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://fifthproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://sixthproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="">FIrst Product Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="affiliateLinkGenerated" type="text" name="affiliate-link" value="http://seventhproduct.html?A=">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```